# how to not include punctuation after url

Tags: javascript, regex, url, punctuation

So I have this code,

```
const urlPattern1 = new RegExp(
  "(https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}[^.,!?:;\\s]+$/?|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}[^.,!?:;\\s]+$/?|https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}[^.,!?:;\\s]+$/?)"
)
```

I would like it to not include any punctuation after the URL. So right now if I type in "www.google.com/..." then it will correctly only register the "www.google.com/".  However, if I type in "www.google.com.!" then I want it to still only register "www.google.com", but right now it registers nothing.  It seems like it is only processing the periods correctly, and any other punctuation (like !) is not getting processed correctly.  Any help?

Comment: I’m trying your regex [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2ayuCI/2) and the only thing it seems to match is `www.google.com` alone, which makes sense since only the third of the four choices you provide is not anchored to the end of the input, and that one is for URLs beginning with `http`/`https`.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(www\.[^\.]+\.\w+)`

Try that. Go to https://regexr.com and put

```
www.google.com
www.google.com/...
www.google.com.!
http://www.google.co-!#{}
```

as the test string, and put that as the regex. It should work.

```
www.google.com // Matches www.google.com
www.google.com/... // Matches www.google.com
www.google.com.!  // Matches www.google.com
http://www.google.co-!#{}  // Matches www.google.co
```